# QTreeWidget / QTreeView Custom Folding to "Always Show" Leaf

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside6

I want to add the ability to keep any number of leaves within a QTreeWidget or QTreeView visible even when the parent is folded. This will give the user the ability to keep only the information they're interested in visible while hiding other information.

How can I implement this effect?

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem

data = {
    "Module 1": {
        "Sub-Module 1": {
            "Leaf 1": "Leaf 1 Info",
            "Leaf 2": "Leaf 2 Info",
            "Leaf 3": "Leaf 3 Info",
            "Leaf 4": "Leaf 4 Info",
        },
        "Sub-Module 2": {
            "Leaf 5": "Leaf 5 Info",
            "Leaf 6": "Leaf 6 Info",
            "Leaf 7": "Leaf 7 Info",
            "Leaf 8": "Leaf 8 Info",
        },
    },
    "Module 2": {
        "Sub-Module 3": {
            "Leaf 9": "Leaf 9 Info",
            "Leaf 10": "Leaf 10 Info",
            "Leaf 11": "Leaf 11 Info",
            "Leaf 12": "Leaf 12 Info",
        },
    },
}


class TreeWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 400)
        tw = QTreeWidget(self)
        tw.setColumnCount(2)
        tw.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        tw.setHeaderLabels(["Name", "Description"])
        self.fill_tree(tw, data)
        self.setCentralWidget(tw)
        tw.expandAll()
        tw.resizeColumnToContents(0)

    def fill_tree(self, widg, data) -> None:
        for key, val in data.items():
            if isinstance(val, str):
                tw_item = QTreeWidgetItem([key, val])
                keep_going = False
            else:
                tw_item = QTreeWidgetItem([key])
                keep_going = True

            if isinstance(widg, QTreeWidget):
                widg.addTopLevelItem(tw_item)
            else:
                widg.addChild(tw_item)

            if keep_going:
                self.fill_tree(tw_item, val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TreeWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

By way of example, if the above code were run and "Leaf 3" were selected to be "always shown" but the rest of the tree was folded, the following is the information desired to be displayed.

```
|-- Module 1
|   `-- Sub-Module 1
|       `-- Leaf 3
`-- Module 2
```

Comment: Seems to me you'll have to subclass QTreeView. The default implementation (as you probably know) is all or nothing -- either a node is collapsed or it isn't. Or, instead of collapsing a node, maybe you can filter the display contents to only show the items you wish? Either approach is going to take some work...

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you only want to show specific children and hide any other sibling or relative that is not directly a parent or grand parent? That would be very difficult with QTreeView alone, since it lays out items on its own, and you'd need to implement *all* that (visual rectangles, selections, drag&drop, highlighting, animations, etc...). Instead, you could use a proxy model, but the problem remains on how to toggle the visibility of the other items.

Comment: @musicamante Correct that is my intent. Sad to hear there isn't a straightforward way to implement.

Comment: @mzimmers I thought a subclassing of methods within a QTreeView may be the path. Any recommendations of which to start looking at? The data() method seemed like a good place to start but seems like I need to go somewhere up-stream from that to detect the fold and that's where I don't know where to go next.

Comment: @ZacharyTaylor after thinking about this a little more, creating a subclass is probably more work than it's worth. Have you looked at setRowHidden()? The implementation would be cumbersome, but it might do what you want.

Comment: @ZacharyTaylor it's not straightforward because that's not the intent of the default expected behavior of a tree view: when you "fold" (the proper term is *collapsed*) a parent, the user expects that its children become hidden. While I can understand your request, it represents some issues in concept: for instance, let's assume that you "collapsed" the "sub-module 1" but not the second, then you toggle the expand state of the top level item. The visibility of the child items depends on *recursion* of the whole sub-tree. As you can understand, that makes the whole implementation quite complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's not easy to achieve.

The most important aspect to consider is that a tree view has a *conventional* and *expected* behavior that users expect: when you "fold" (the proper term is *collapse*) an item, the user expects that all its children (including [great-]grand children) are collapsed as well: only the parent is expected to be visible.

Luckily, Qt is quite extensible and allows us to find some work arounds, but they are not cost-free.

The most important problem is that the user (righteously) expects to see a *visible* hint that shows whether an item is expanded or collapsed. Qt, in its "simplicity", just *assumes* that aspect based on the current view state, meaning that the "expanding decoration" will be shown according to the fact that a parent has (and shows) its children or not.

Then, there is a conceptual problem in this request: what if *one* of the children is "collapsed", but any of the other is not? What should the parent show? And what if the parent is "expanded", but *all* its children are not?

That's another reason for which, considering UX aspects, such interface is normally not provided (nor desired) in a generic toolkit implementation.

Still, we want that behavior... so?

One possibility is to work around all these problems, which requires us to take care of many aspects:

- ensure that the "virtual" collapsed/expanded state is persistent, based on the parent;
- override the drawing, possibly using a [QProxyStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qproxystyle.html);
- use recursive functions that take care of the expanded/collapsed state of a parent;
- take care of user interaction;

With the above in mind, here is a possible (though, imperfect) solution:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

data = {
# ... as above
}

ExpandedRole = Qt.UserRole + 100 # a custom role to "override" the parent state


class ProxyStyle(QProxyStyle):
    _childIndex = None
    def drawPrimitive(self, elem, opt, qp, widget=None):
        if elem == self.PE_IndicatorBranch and self._childIndex:
            # use the _childIndex reference for the *first* call to 
            # drawPrimitive only, then revert to the default painting
            if self._childIndex.model().hasChildren(self._childIndex):
                opt.state |= self.State_Children
                if not self._childIndex.data(ExpandedRole):
                    opt.state &= ~self.State_Open
            self._childIndex = None

        super().drawPrimitive(elem, opt, qp, widget)


class ProxyStyle(QProxyStyle):
    _childIndex = None
    def drawPrimitive(self, elem, opt, qp, widget=None):
        if elem == self.PE_IndicatorBranch and self._childIndex:
            if self._childIndex.model().hasChildren(self._childIndex):
                opt.state |= self.State_Children
                if not self._childIndex.data(ExpandedRole):
                    opt.state &= ~self.State_Open
            self._childIndex = None

        super().drawPrimitive(elem, opt, qp, widget)


class TreeWidget(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAnimated(False)
        # override the internal collapsed signal
        self.collapsed.connect(self.expand)
        # do the same for internal calls for expanding
        self.expanded.connect(lambda index: self.setExpanded(index, True))

    def drawBranches(self, qp, rect, index):
        # set a "reference" index for the style, necessary for the indentation
        self.style()._childIndex = index
        super().drawBranches(qp, rect, index)

    def isCheckedRecursive(self, index):
        # tell if an item or any of its children is checked (not "hideable")
        if index.data(Qt.CheckStateRole):
            return True
        model = index.model()
        for row in range(model.rowCount(index)):
            childIndex = model.index(row, 0, index)
            if self.isCheckedRecursive(childIndex):
                return True
        return False

    def setExpanded(self, parent, expanded):
        # an overridden "slot"
        model = self.model()
        if not model.hasChildren(parent):
            return False
        wasExpanded = parent.data(ExpandedRole)
        if expanded == wasExpanded:
            return wasExpanded
        model.setData(parent, expanded, ExpandedRole)
        r = self.visualRect(parent)
        r.setLeft(0)
        self.viewport().update(r)
        hasExpanded = False
        for row in range(model.rowCount(parent)):
            childIndex = model.index(row, 0, parent)
            if self.setExpanded(childIndex, expanded):
                hasExpanded = True
            elif expanded:
                self.setRowHidden(row, parent, False)
            else:
                self.setRowHidden(row, parent, 
                    not self.isCheckedRecursive(childIndex))
        return hasExpanded

    def toggleExpanded(self, index):
        expand = index.data(ExpandedRole)
        if expand is not None:
            expand = not expand
        else:
            for r in range(self.model().rowCount(index)):
                if self.isRowHidden(r, index):
                    expand = True
                    break
            else:
                expand = False

        self.setExpanded(index, expand)
        return expand

    def hasExpandArrowAtPos(self, pos):
        # if the mouse position is in the "arrow" rect, return the index
        index = self.indexAt(pos)
        if not index.isValid() or not self.model().hasChildren(index):
            return
        parent = index.parent()
        rootDecorated = self.rootIsDecorated()
        if not parent.isValid() and not rootDecorated:
            return
        indent = self.indentation()
        if rootDecorated:
            itemIndent = 0
        else:
            itemIndent = -indent
        while parent.isValid():
            itemIndent += indent
            parent = parent.parent()

        position = self.header().sectionViewportPosition(0)
        itemRect = self.visualRect(index)
        rect = QRect(position + itemIndent, itemRect.y(), 
            indent, itemRect.height())

        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        
        opt.rect = rect
        arrowRect = self.style().subElementRect(
            QStyle.SE_TreeViewDisclosureItem, opt, self)
        if arrowRect.contains(pos):
            return index

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            index = self.hasExpandArrowAtPos(event.pos())
            if index:
                self.toggleExpanded(index)
                self.setCurrentIndex(index)
                return
        super().mousePressEvent(event)


class TreeWindow(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def fill_tree(self, widg, data) -> None:
        for key, val in data.items():
            # ...
            if keep_going:
                self.fill_tree(tw_item, val)
            else:
                tw_item.setCheckState(0, Qt.Checked)
```

Note that the above implementation is *not* perfect.

For instance:

- it doesn't consider double clicking a parent
- it doesn't properly work with keyboard navigation; if you want to implement that aspect, you *must* do it within a [`moveCursor`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreeview.html#moveCursor) override, consider the current index *and* viewport scroll position, eventually expand/collapse the parent or current item and return the new resulting index, otherwise just revert to the default implementation;
- some internal functions and behaviors might not work as expected, such as direct calls to `expand()`, `collapse()`, `expandToDepth()` or `expandRecursively()`;
- as mentioned above, it's not a good choice from the UX perspective: it's not really intuitive, and the parent/grandparent inconsistency might be very confusing to the user;

Frankly, while I can see the need for such a behavior, I would not really suggest it. The UX aspect is what most worries me, because it's not intuitive: if I want to collapse an item, I don't expect it to still show its children.

A better solution, instead, would be to use a [*proxy* model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) and a specifically dedicated UI element to toggle the visible state that would *filter* the defined items: it would then just be a matter of calling [`invalidateFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#invalidateFilter) and implementing [`filterAcceptsRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow) using a common function that checks whether an item (or any of its [grand]children) should be shown or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and effort (I hope my donation helps). This helps me understand things a lot further, I will study the code more. It also encourages me to re-evaluate my approach. Maybe this would be better implemented by allowing the user to select elements from the QTree (through checkboxes) to create a new QTree that has only the elements they're interested in at the time. I'll give it more thought.

Comment: Well, that's *some* donation!  Thank you, I really appreciate it... As said, I understand the need for such requirement, but the issue of *clear* representation of the "filtered" view may be an important aspect to consider. After thinking again about this, I was considering another possible solution, which would toggle between 3 states: expanded, collapsed and *filtered*, with that state showing a different icon instead of the normal expand/collapse indicator, which might result more visually intuitive; I'll think a bit more, maybe I'll provide a further improvement (or another answer).